# How to get the counts of a grouped variable and add another variable with counts in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that reports observation of individuals with 3 columns: id-observation, id-household, adults(1 if yes, 0 if no).  I would like to create a new table grouped by households with 3 columns: id_household, size of each household (number of observations in each household), nºof adults in each household.

I am using this to get a new table with the household and the size, but I don´t know how to include the number of adults in each household:

```
household_data_2018<-data2018%>%
  group_by(household_id,)%>%
  summarise(count=n())%>%
```

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 1/0 values in `adults` column you can `sum` it to get total number of adults.

```
library(dplyr)

household_data_2018 <- data2018 %>%
                           group_by(household_id)%>%
                           summarise(count=n(), n_adults = sum(adults))
```