# Conditionally count all values in column without listing values explicitly

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a dataset that looks something like the following:

```
Col1 | Col2
-----|-----
dog  | red
cat  | red
cat  | green
dog  | pink
cat  | orange
```

I would like to group the data by Col1, and then have n number of columns that correlate to the unique values in Col2. The end result would look something like this:

```
Col1 | red | green | pink | orange 
-----|-----|-------|------|-------
dog  | 1   | 0     | 1    | 0
cat  | 1   | 1     | 0    | 1
```

The most obvious way to do this would be using the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386796/how-to-get-the-counts-of-a-grouped-variable-and-add-another-variable-with-counts).

```
df%>%
        group_by(Col1)%>%
        summarise( n_red = sum(Col2 == 'red'),
                   n_pink = sum(Col2 == 'pink'),
                   n_green = sum(Col2 == 'green'),
                   n_green = sum(Col2 == 'green'))
```

However, the number of different values in Col2 is sufficiently large that typing out the above code is too time intensive.

How would someone get the same output, without having to type `n_<color> = sum(Col2 == '<color>')` for each option

Answer (score 0):

Easiest/tidiest way could be to count each Col1/Col2 unique pair then pivot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~ Col1, ~ Col2,
   "dog", "red",
   "cat", "red",
   "cat", "green",
   "dog", "pink",
   "cat", "orange"
) |> 
  count(Col1, Col2) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Col2, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   Col1  green orange   red  pink
#>   <chr> <int>  <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 cat       1      1     1     0
#> 2 dog       0      0     1     1
```